# Return null value after page PostBack in Mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, http-post, entity-framework-5, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I want to create **Invoice Create View**. 
My viewModel as follow:

```
public class InvoiceCreate
{
    public IEnumerable<InvoiceItem> InvoiceItems { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Recipient> Recipients { get; set; }
    public Sender Sender { get; set; }
    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Get method as follow:

```
  public ActionResult Create()
    {
        InvoiceCreate invoice = new InvoiceCreate();
        invoice.InvoiceItems = (new Invoice.Model.InvoiceItem[20]).AsQueryable();
        invoice.Recipients = (new Recipient[20]).AsQueryable();
        invoice.Sender = new Sender() { Adrress="O.Karimov"};
        invoice.Invoice = new Invoice.Model.Invoice();
        return View(invoice);
    }
```

My view as follow:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { id = "submitForm" }))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.name);
<div>
    <div id="head">
        <h1>Invoice</h1>
        <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Invoice.InvoiceNumber, new { placeholder = "Invoice number" })
        </div>... @for (var itemIndex = 1; itemIndex < Model.Recipients.Count(); itemIndex++)
            {
                <div class="recipient-row unvisible">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" style="float: left; margin: 6px;">×</button>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Recipients.ElementAt(itemIndex).CustomerName, new { placeholder = "Contact name" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Recipients.ElementAt(itemIndex).Email, new { type = "email", placeholder = "example@mail.ru" })
                </div>
            }
        <div class="input-append date" data-form="datepicker" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Invoice.InvoiceDate, new { placeholder = "Invoice date", @Value = System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), @class = "grd-white", data_form = "datepicker" })
        </div>
    </div>  <button type="submit" id="btnSave" name="Command" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="Command" value="SaveDraft" class="btn btn-info">Save as draft</button>
    <button type="submit" id="btnCancel" name="Command" value="Cancel" onclick="$('#submitForm').submit()" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
    <input type="submit" name="name" value=" " />
</div>
}
```

Post method as follow:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(InvoiceCreate invoice, string Command)
    {
        switch (Command)
        {
            case "Save":
                {

                }
                break;
            case "SaveDraft":
                {

                }
                break;
            default:
                return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index");
        }
        return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index");
    }
```

My problem is that when I click any button in view in my Post method **invoice** variable is null. How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ViewModel, you need to have a Contructor, initializing the complex properties, like collections.

I think this will "help" the model binder fill your model.